# Checking length of text-box content in javascript with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I use the following regex to validate a text box's content:

```
^[A-Za-z.]*[A-Za-z][-A-Za-z0-9,/()&:. ]*$
```

I would like to validate the length of my text-box in this regexp.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Use the `maxlength` property.

Comment: i want to give size only 1-128 with this regexp.

Comment: By "text-box", do you mean textarea (multi-line) or text input (single line)? On a text input, use the `maxlength` attribute. On textarea, you have to manually check the value length.

Comment: Why a regular expression? Why not simply compare the length of the string?

Comment: i mean by text-area (like text-box for name validation who can take only min-1 and max-128 character). but i want to handle it using regexp

Comment: Ok textarea with size=1-128 but why do you need regex?

Comment: Using a regular expression for this would be a complete overkill... If all you want to do is match the length, then check the maxlength/whatever value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check a string's length and format with a regex, you can use numbered repeaters:

```
^[a-z]{1,128}$
```

However, if you have a succession of unkown numbers of character classes, you can use [zero-length positive lookeahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at the beginning of the regex:

```
^(?=.{1,128}$)[a-z]*[a-z0-9]*$
```

So for your regex:

```
^(?=.{1,128}$)[A-Za-z.]*[A-Za-z][-A-Za-z0-9,/()&:. ]*$
```

If you can though, I'd still suggest checking `myString.length` instead.

Comment: That is some of the ugliest, most unnecessary regex I've ever seen... And I'm almost certain it won't do the intended job properly. It could match: ".....a ,", but would fail to match "(test)" or "123".

Comment: According to his regex, he doesn't want to match those…

Comment: I know. My point is that the original question was clearly misleading, in that you've been asked to solve the incorrect problem in an incorrect way.

Comment: Okay, I assumed that the comment being on my answer, you were criticizing the answer